# PowerDesigner and Bizagi: exchange data and models

Tags: powerdesigner, bizagi

I 'm using PowerDesigner 16.1 to create cdm and pdm models, and Bigazi to create Business Procees models, I want to exchange data and models between both of it. So I need a file  format that is supported by the two tools

Comment: _Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it._

Comment: The problem that I have choosen bmp as a file format which normally supported by PD and Bigazi. I  have created a business model by bigazi and I have  exported it to BNPM, but I couldn't open it via PD; "PD failed to read the file" so I need to help me to solve this problem or to tell me if there is another file format supported by both without errors. thanks

Comment: `bpm` is, I guess, the evident trigram for a file containing a BPM model, for both PowerDesigner, and Bigazi, but I guess, again, that their contents does not match at all. PowerDesigner supports import, and export of BPMN2 files, which might be more standard (if Bigazi can work with them).

Comment: Yes. Use BPMN2 file format. Is it supported by Bigazi?

Comment: But it is not supported by the PD  which I 'm using (Problem of licence) so I ' m looking for a tool as converter from bpmn to bpm (a file format supported by Bizagi to  one suppored  by PD) or to replace Bizagi with another tool.